# Add a string with a network-wide ban reason into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, international-sites, network-wide-suspension

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337609/roy-montague

> [image]

I've found the string with key `229e40df2284bc1723ab27d08cd748eb`:

> This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.

But it looks like the `$reason$` part (here: "network-wide") is not in the Transifex system, and we can't translate it. Could you do something with it?

Comment: When you as a moderator suspend a user, will a translated reason be chosen?

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser I don't have such option at all. I can ban user for specific time and only on SOru. Probably, this ban was given by EN moderator (or SE emploee).

Comment: If you suspend a user for any reason (let's assume a template about low-quality questions), will the shown reason be translated or in English?

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser mmm, the message about ban period is translated (e.g. " 365 дней за третье серьёзное нарушение"). There is no additional field for **reason**.

Comment: On English sites, there is sometimes a reason shown. Example "for voting irregularities". Does this happen in Russian SE too? (Example will follow)

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser yeh, those reasons are translated (e.g. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/athari?tab=topactivity). The problem appears only with **network-wide**, as I can see.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. AFAIK network-wide suspensions are regular suspensions with the value "network-wide" in the reason column for any site. These are applied by a script run by an SE employee (suspension from the referenced should be imposed by Community user?). So I think unfortunately this problem won't be fixed, but let's wait for an official answer.

Comment: Technically I think the text "network-wide" is separate from/can be shown in addition to a possible reason, at least based on what the code looks like now. But yeah, the issue is that the text "network-wide" needs to be made translatable. Anyway, I've passed this report on to the relevant dev team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this went live Aug 10, 2023. A few separate translatable strings with different `$reason$` values are available, including "network-wide". In other cases, it falls back to the version that injects the `$reason$` string.

This isn't going to be perfect, but should solve the majority of cases.